# How to make an API accessible all the time and not just when the project is executed?

Tags: azure, rest, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making my first mobile app using Xamarin.Forms and FreshMVVM as the architecture and I want this app to get info off my SQL database (which is located in azure) by calling an API Rest. I already know how to develop an Api, and all the SQL and Azure related stuff, as well as how to get info from my API. 
But what I don't know is how to access this API when the project in which is created is not executed, in other words, I don't know how to make my API Rest accessible all the time, so the App can access to it whenever is needed. 
How do you do this?

Thank you all for your time, hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish the API to a web host.  Azure App Services.  AWS.  Digital Ocean VM running a web server.  Possibly GoDaddy, though I have never used them.  Your own server.